# All node links in Umbraco turned to #

Tags: umbraco

Im using Umbraco 4.7 and registered a special property called umbracoUrlName which enables me to override the default generated url to any node. When trying to load a page all I get is **"Object moved to here."**

This error did occur **after** I implemented the **umbracoUrlName** property

I have done this on multiple sites before and have never experienced this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use the republish feature which I don't think is available in the GUI anywhere. This one is far more powerful than the one available in the context menu in the content section when right clicking the content node.

http://mysite.com/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

It'll take a while to run but it solved most of my problems.

Comment: This is due to a corrupted cache file (/App_Data/umbraco.config) which should be disabled whilst developing. Edit the XmlCacheEnabled element in the settings file (/config/umbracoSettings.config) from "True" to "False".  Then delete the cache file, and republish your site. This will ensure you don't get this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before. My solution was to go into the back office and right click the content node and select republish entire site. It doesn't actually republish everything. It just triggers the cache file to be rebuilt. It may take a few seconds to propagate.

If that doesn't fix it try republishing a single node to see if the URL changes from the #. Then the rest should update as well.

Comment: Close enough, I had to use the republish feature which I believe isn't available in the GUI